# AudioKit convolution

Tags: audiokit

I'm trying to use the Convolution Reverb in a mac os app.
AudioKit 4.03

The playground example works for me, but when I try to replicate it in my app, I get this error, and no audio.

2017-11-18 20:21:36.116436-0500 convolutionVerb testing[37554:4533072] [avae] AVAEInternal.h:69:_AVAE_Check: required condition is false: [AVAudioEngine.mm:348:AttachNode: (node != nil)]
2017-11-18 20:21:36.116642-0500 convolutionVerb testing[37554:4533072] Failed to set (contentViewController) user defined inspected property on (NSWindow): required condition is false: node != nil

Here's my code (which is just a slightly modified version of the AudioKit playground)

class ViewController: NSViewController {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



    do {
         file = try AKAudioFile(readFileName: "SAMPLES/Bell.wav")
         player = try AKAudioPlayer(file: file)
    }
    catch {print("DIDN'T LOAD")}

    player.looping = true




    let stairwell = bundle.url(forResource: "stairwell", withExtension: "wav", subdirectory: "Impulse Responses")
        let dish = bundle.url(forResource: "dish", withExtension: "wav", subdirectory: "Impulse Responses")

        stairwellConvolution = AKConvolution(player,impulseResponseFileURL: stairwell!,partitionLength: 8_192)
        dishConvolution = AKConvolution(player,impulseResponseFileURL: dish!,partitionLength: 8_192)


        mixer = AKDryWetMixer(stairwellConvolution, dishConvolution, balance: 0.5)
    dryWetMixer = AKDryWetMixer(player, mixer, balance: 0.5)



    AudioKit.output = dryWetMixer
    AudioKit.start()


    stairwellConvolution.start()
    dishConvolution.start()

    player.play()


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit hard to say for sure this is correct, but I'll venture a guess that it has something to do with your view controller life cycle.  You have this AudioKit set up code in viewDidLoad which might not be safe.  I think its at least a worthwhile step to put the audio code into an Engine or Conductor singleton class accessible across your project and not tied to UI life cycles.

Comment: thanks.  I created a singleton and call (init)  from the AppDelegate.  But I still get:              2017-11-18 22:06:27.826993-0500 convolutionVerb testing[40604:4626340] [avae] AVAEInternal.h:69:_AVAE_Check: required condition is false: [AVAudioEngine.mm:348:AttachNode: (node != nil)]
2017-11-18 22:06:27.827318-0500 convolutionVerb testing[40604:4626340] required condition is false: node != nil

Comment: Okay, thanks for trying that first. You want to share your project or do a screenshare?

Comment: Yes, I can send you my project!

Comment: I've uploaded to gitHub.            https://github.com/paul-hsu/convolutionVerb-testing